# python plt barh does cannot properly display the bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have problems when drawing horizontal bar chart
firstly if we draw it in plt.bar

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.bar(range_df.range_start, range_df.cum_trade_vol, width=30)
plt.show()
```

[image]

but if we draw it in plt.barh

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.barh(range_df.range_start, range_df.cum_trade_vol)
plt.show()
```

its either
[image]

or like:

[image]

**The problem, I think, is because the crowded data that left too few gaps.
What can we do to properly draw the graph? (since we cannot set width with barh? or can we?)
Maybe another plot package?**

**Please do not reset the y axis value as the current value is important**

The data can be downloaded at
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y8fHazEFhVR_u2KL6uUsBqv0qmXOd2xT/view?usp=share_link

the notebook is at:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MbjJE4B-mspDRqCYXnDf8hyFRK_uLmRp?usp=sharing

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am somewhat unsure of what you are talking about. When writing the horizontal plot, you drop `width` parameter. There is an equivalent version for `plt.barh` which is `height`. So try

```
plt.barh(range_df.range_start, range_df.cum_trade_vol, height=30)
```

Comment: Great! Sorry about the confusion, but yeah, you had the answer I seek.